# # Error: TypeError: file <maya console> line 49: Error retrieving default arguments #

Tags: python, maya, mel

I am trying to import the xyz values from a csv file to some objects in maya using the following code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds


def getDataByFrame(fileName):
    # Open and read lines from some csv file
    data = fileName
    f = open(data)
    line = f.readline()

    dataPerFrame = []
    original, object, x, y, z = line.split(",") 

    while line:

        frame, object, x, y, z = line.split(",") 
        if frame != original:
            print dataPerFrame
            return dataPerFrame
        #print frame
        #print x
        #print y
        #print z
        else:
            dataPerFrame.append(line)

        line = f.readline() 

    f.close()



def animate(data):
    for i in range (len(data)):
        print "dada"
        frame, objectName, x, y, z = data[i].split(",")    
        print frame
        print objectName
        print x
        print y
        print z
        frame = float(frame)
        x = float(x)
        y = float(y)
        z = float(z)


        **cmds.currentTime(frame) 
        cmds.setAttr (objectName+".tx", x)
        cmds.setKeyframe( v=x, at='translateX' )
        cmds.setAttr (objectName+".ty", y)
        cmds.setKeyframe( v=y, at='translateY' )
        cmds.setAttr (objectName+".tz", z)
        cmds.setKeyframe( v=z, at='translateZ' )**

data = getDataByFrame("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Stickman/testing.csv")
animate(data)
```

The problem is I am getting the Error: "Error retrieving default arguments"
The highlighted code was translated from a mel code that I found on the official maya help website:

```
global proc getAnim(string $fileName, string $objectName)
{
 //open the file for reading
 $fileId=`fopen $fileName "r"`;

 //get the first line of text
 string $nextLine = `fgetline $fileId`;

 //while $nextline is not emtpy(end of file) do the following 

 while ( size( $nextLine ) > 0 ) {

 //tokenize(split) line into separate elements of an array 
 string $rawAnimArray[];
 tokenize ($nextLine, " ",$rawAnimArray);
 //place each element of the array into separate variables 
 print $rawAnimArray;
 float $frame=$rawAnimArray[0];
 float $x=$rawAnimArray[1];
 float $y=$rawAnimArray[2];
 float $z=$rawAnimArray[3];

 //change the currentTime and set keys for tx, ty, tz
 currentTime $frame ;
 setAttr ($objectName+".tx") $x;
 setKeyframe ($objectName+".tx");
 setAttr ($objectName+".ty") $y;
 setKeyframe ($objectName+".ty");
 setAttr ($objectName+".tz") $z;
 setKeyframe ($objectName+".tz");
 //get the next line in the ascii file. 
 $nextLine = `fgetline $fileId`;
 }
 //close file 
 fclose $fileId;
}
```

I am not sure if it is because I didn't translate this lines of code correctly to Python or is it because of something else.

Comment: Don't you have to include the object's name in `setKeyframe`, or at least have it selected?

Answer (score 0):

just looking at your code, here are two errors :

line 47 : `**cmds.currentTime(frame)` -> `cmds.currentTime(frame)`

line 53 : `cmds.setKeyframe( v=z, at='translateZ' )**` -> `cmds.setKeyframe(objectName, v=z, at='translateZ' )`

For the animate, I would do something like this instead. The first attr and attr axes are here just as example if you want to add rotation and scale into your csv.

```
def animate(data):
    for d in data:
        visibility = []
        frame, objectName = d.split(",")[:2]
        values = [float(i) for i in  d.split(",")[2:]]
        # just for the fun to see if there is a visibility value
        guess = [len(values)/3, len(values)%3
        if guess[1]:
            visibility = ('v', values[0])
            values = values[1:]
        attr = ['t','r', 's'][:guess[0]/3]
        attr_axes = [i+j for i in attr for j in ['x', 'y', 'z']]
        feed = zip(attr_axes, values)
        if visibility:
            feed += visibility
        for d in feed:
            cmds.setKeyframe(objectName, v=d[1], at=d[0], t=frame)

data = ["10, pSphere1, 1,2,3", "20, pSphere1, 5,6,7"]
# EXAMPLE : data = [ "10, pSphere1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4,5 , 6, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3"]
# EXAMPLE : data = [frame, obj, visibility, tx, ty, tz, rx, ry, rz, sx, sy, sz]
animate(data)
```

if you want just the necessary code :

```
def animate(data):
    for d in data:
        frame, objectName = d.split(",")[:2]
        values = [float(i) for i in  d.split(",")[2:]]
        attr = ['t']
        attr_axes = [i+j for i in attr for j in ['x', 'y', 'z']]
        feed = zip(attr_axes, values) # + visibility
        for d in feed:
            cmds.setKeyframe(objectName, v=d[1], at=d[0], t=frame)

data = ["10, pSphere1, 1,2,3", "20, pSphere1, 5,6,7"]
animate(data)
```

---EDIT---

Last tips, if you want to edit lots of object, I will regroup objects and attributes with the same value because it can be really slow otherwise